# Launching my app from GooglePlay app destroys activity instead of resume

Tags: android, android-activity, google-play, google-play-services, activity-lifecycle

If my app is already running and I try to open my app from GooglePlay or Play Games, system is destroy activity, and recreate it instead of just resume.

My config-changes is:
`android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize`

android:lauchMode is default

What to fix it?

Comment: why is that even a problem

Answer (score 0):

In general, your app could get killed at any moment for any reason (eg low memory on the device), so your App should cope with this gracefully.